# how can I make a link for each image in slider

Tags: jquery, html, json, slider, jquery-cycle2

I want to create each image in slider clickable with its own link based on `data[i].id`.
I have no idea how to do this(I'm using library cycle2)

Could anybody give me some suggestion?

```
<script>
    var img;
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON('http://localhost/daily_posts.ja.json', function(data){
                for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                    img = "<img src='" + data[i].media.thumbnail + "' data-cycle-title='"+ data[i].title +"'/>"
                    $('.cycle-slideshow').append(img);
                }
                $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('reinit');
            });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-caption-plugin="caption2">

        <div class="cycle-caption"></div>
        <div class="cycle-overlay"></div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It matters with what response.data.records contains either image source path or base string of actual image. If it contains source path then you need to create images in code.

Comment: thank you for answering, but I'm a novice in angularjs. Could you give me a code guideline to create images?

Comment: Replace your <li ng-repeat= "x in sliders"></li> tag with <li ng-repeat= "x in sliders"><img ng-src="{{x.thumbnail}}" /></li>

Comment: OR if your response is base64 string then use <img ng-src="{{'data:image/png;base64,' + x,thumbnail'}}" >

Answer (score 0):

The general tutorial of Angularjs https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial builds an app, where images and json data are loaded to build a slider. I can recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your img tag inside anchor element

```
var img = "<a href="+data[i].link+"><img //rest of your code></a>"
```

Comment: after I did like this, the slide doesn't work  all images display altogether

Comment: check browser console(inspect element) for errors to get a hint.